# Datalist Like Structure In ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC.

I have created a page in web forms which contains a DataList control. Below is the markup

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlProducts" ShowFooter="true" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4"
            BorderStyle="None">
            <FooterStyle ForeColor="Red" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True" />                
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table class="list">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25%;">
                                <a href='<%#Eval("ProductId","ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId={0}") %>'>
                                    <img width="120px" height="120px" src='<%#Eval("productImage", "admin/Uploads/Product/{0}") %>' alt='<%#Eval("ProductName") %>' />
                                </a>
                                <br />
                                <a href='<%#Eval("ProductId","ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId={0}") %>'>
                                    <%#Eval("ProductName") %>
                                </a>
                                <br />
                                <span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); font-size: 11px;">
                                    <%#Eval("productDescription")%>
                                </span>
                                <br />
                                <span style="color: rgb(153, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-family: Rupee Foradian">`</span>
                                    <%#Eval("productPrice")%>
                                </span>
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>                    
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" Text="Coming Soon" runat="server" Visible='<%#bool.Parse((dtlProducts.Items.Count==0).ToString())%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

This markup generates the below structure
[image]

Now, I am trying to achieve the same using ASP.NET MVC 4

This is what I have tried in razor:

```
<table style="border-style:none;border-collapse:collapse;" id="tblProducts">
<tr>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Product)
    {
        <td>
            <table class="list">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 25%;">
                            <a href="ClientHome/Index/@item.ProductId">
                                <img width="120px" height="120px" alt="@item.ProductName" src="../Uploads/Product/@item.Image">
                            </a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="ClientHome/Index/@item.ProductId">
                                @item.ProductName
                            </a>
                            <br>
                            <span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); font-size: 11px;">
                                @item.Description
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span style="color: rgb(153, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;">
                                <span style="font-family: Rupee Foradian">`</span>
                                @item.Price
                            </span>
                            <br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    }
</tr>
</table>
```

This generates the below structure
[image]

What exactly should I change in my razor?

Comment: Does it have to be a table layout or could you live with a responsive Grid-like layout?

Comment: This is a styling issue, not razor. Since it not really tabular data, consider rendering the contents in a div styled with `float:left` and `width:25%`

Comment: @Serv What does that mean?

Comment: It means you have a fixed layout which does not adapt to screen sizes very well. A responsive layout adapts to the screen size. For example: if the width gets smaller because its viewed on a smartphone, the columsn go down from 4, to 3 to 2 to single columsn depending on the available viewspace.

Comment: +1 @StephenMuecke this does helps a bit.

Comment: @Serv Any how will do

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am using your css recommendation. but instead of 4 columns it gives 3

Comment: Probably because you have borders - add `box-sizing:border-box;` to the enclosing `div`

Comment: @StephenMuecke looks like I have misunderstood messed it up.. can you please tell the full code

Comment: Busy now, but I'll have a look in an hour

Comment: @StephenMuecke Alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **In Model:**

```
public class ProductList
{
    public List<List<ProductMaster>> lstPrdList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

## **In View:**

```
@model ShoppingCart_MVC4.Models.ProductList
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model.lstPrdList)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var items in item)
                {
                    <td>
                        <table class="list">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="ClientHome/Index/@items.ProductId">
                                            <img width="120" height="120" alt="@items.ProductName" src="../Uploads/Product/@items.Image">
                                        </a>
                                        <br>
                                        <a href="ClientHome/Index/@items.ProductId">
                                            @items.ProductName
                                        </a>
                                        <br>
                                        <span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); font-size: 11px;">
                                            @items.Description
                                        </span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span style="color: rgb(153, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;">
                                            <span style="font-family: Rupee Foradian">`</span>
                                            @items.Price
                                        </span>
                                        <br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

## **In Controller:**

```
public class ClientHomeController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        ProductList objPrdList = new ProductList();
        List<List<ProductMaster>> lstPrdList = new List<List<ProductMaster>>();
        List<ProductMaster> inner = new List<ProductMaster>();
        inner = db.ProductMasters.Where(x => x.isActive == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).Take(10).ToList();
        int skip = 0;
        int take = 4;
        List<ProductMaster> pm;
        for (int i = 0; i < inner.Count / take; i++)
        {
            pm = new List<ProductMaster>();
            pm = inner.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
            lstPrdList.Add(pm);
            skip += take;
        }
        pm = new List<ProductMaster>();
        pm = inner.Skip(skip).Take(inner.Count-skip).ToList();
        lstPrdList.Add(pm);
        objPrdList.lstPrdList = lstPrdList;
        return View(objPrdList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a styling issue, not razor. Since it not really tabular data, consider rendering the contents in a div styled with `float:left` and `width:25%`

The view might look something like this (note I recommend using a view model for the product properties rather that `ViewBag`, where the view model contains relevant properties including the image path)

```
@model IEnumerable<YourAssembly.ProductVM>
....
<div class="container">
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <div class="image">
      <img src= "@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt=@item.ProductName />
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      @Html.ActionLink(item.ProductName, "Index", "ClientHome", new { id = item.ProductId })
    </div>
    <div class="description">@item.Description</div>
    <div class="price">@item.Price</div>
  }
</div>
```

CSS (just making a guess for most of the properties and you will need to modify this to suit your needs)

```
.container {
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  border: grey 1px solid;
  float:left;
  // set other properties for font etc. if not inherited from body
}
.product {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.image {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.name {
  text-align:center;
}
.description {
  text-align:center;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  font-size: 11px;
}
.price {
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(153, 0, 0);
  font-family: Rupee Foradian
}
```

[Refer simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f59atpaw/) indicating the styling here

Comment: thanks a lot for taking all that pain.. i really appreciate that.. but i achieved it with another method.. will add the solution in some time

Comment: @mathewtinus, No problem, but your solution is rendering tables within tables which is awful html (and slow) - and its not even tabular data!

Comment: Actually the inner table can be avoided and the elements can be adjusted using css.. i did it in a hurry.. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve using Razor you can try this

But same can be achieved using CSS(recommended)

```
<table style="border-style:none;border-collapse:collapse;" id="tblProducts">
    @{decimal count = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Product)
    {

        if(@count % 4 == 0)
        {
            @Html.Raw("<tr>")
        }
            <td>
                <table class="list">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25%;">
                                <a href="ClientHome/Index/@item.ProductId">
                                    <img width="120px" height="120px" alt="@item.ProductName" src="../Uploads/Product/@item.Image">
                                </a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="ClientHome/Index/@item.ProductId">
                                    @item.ProductName
                                </a>
                                <br>
                                <span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); font-size: 11px;">
                                    @item.Description
                                </span>
                                <br>
                                <span style="color: rgb(153, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;">
                                    <span style="font-family: Rupee Foradian">`</span>
                                    @item.Price
                                </span>
                                <br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        if (@count % 4 == 0)
        {
            @Html.Raw("</tr>")
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
    }

</table>
```

Comment: i am using css for now but i dont get the exact desired output instead of 4 columns i get 3.